# Gmail notifica que email geralmente é usado para roubar informações quando eu utilizo content-type ="text/html; charset=utf-8"

Tags: c#, email, gmail

Utilizo a API do Gmail para enviar e-mail's marketing, e sempre respeito os limites e as normas anti-spam.E ontem comecei a enviar emails em massa, em média 2.000 por dia, porém após um tempo percebi que os usuários recebem a seguinte informação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E isso afeta a confiança, meu e-mail tem um HTML que apenas redireciona os usuários para links do meu site, onde tem imagens gratuitas por exemplo. Fui investigar o motivo e removi o *content-type ="text/html; charset=utf-8"* do Header do meu e-mail e a mensagem sumiu,porém meu e-mail virou puro texto, ele não lê mais como HTML.

Obs:.Gostaria de saber se tem como corrigir isso de alguma forma, utilizo a API do Gmail(não é o SMTP) com C#.

> EDIT: Fiz um teste e enviei por SMTP do Gmail e ele não notifica como
>   spam ou seja estou tendo esse problema em especifico com a API DO
>   GMAIL

Comment: Os links de destino são do mesmo domínio da conta que envia o e-mail?

Comment: São sim, todos sem excessão

Comment: Eu fiz um teste agora, e quando envio por SMTP ele não notifica o SPAM, quando eu envio por API GMAIL sim

Comment: no envio por smpt você botou o content-type como html ou deixou só na marcação do html?

Comment: Dizer que email marketing não é spam é como dizer que água não é molhada.

Comment: @Renan Spam é vocÊ enviar 300milhoes de emails para uma mesma pessoa, insistir naquilo... email marketing não é spam se você tem um certo controle sobre isso

Comment: @LeandroAngelo coloquei content type html certinho !

Comment: @Renan email marketing não é SPAM quando o destinatário aceitou receber quando se cadastrou no remetente sob aviso de que isso poderia acontecer, e que na mensagem contenha um link de exclusão (opt-out).

Comment: @dvd eu entendo a legalidade e licitude do web/click wrap, mas a minha opinião sobre contrato de adesão eletrônico é a mesma do Neil Gaiman: nem Satanás conseguiria ser tão ardiloso quanto as pessoas que fazem isso.

Comment: @Renan É, mas é assim q funciona mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você não deseja que o seu spam enviado via API seja marcado como spam pelo Gmail, [vamos ver o que diz a documentação](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=pt-BR).

[image]

E lá diz, e eu parafraseio:

> O [Gmail Postmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6227174) fornece aos remetentes métricas para parâmetros como reputação, taxa de spam, feedback loop, etc. Isso pode ajudar você a verificar a conformidade com as diretrizes para remetentes de e-mail em massa do Gmail, bem como identificar problemas com o filtro de spam.

Ou seja, aqui você vê como você está perante a Alphabet.

Mais pra baixo tem um detalhe importante. Ênfases minhas:

> As classificações de e-mails **dependem muito do que é denunciado pelos usuários**. Os usuários do Gmail podem marcar ou desmarcar mensagens como spam e mover as mensagens que não são spam entre as guias da Caixa de entrada. Em ambos os casos, **o Gmail aprende com as correções dos usuários** e, com o tempo, **ajusta automaticamente a classificação de acordo com as preferências dos usuários**.

Ou seja, não basta apenas fazer tudo do jeito que eles orientam. Se mesmo seguindo tudo à risca você irritar os usuários do Gmail, fica marcado como spammer e ponto-final.

Seguindo adiante, tem dicas do que mais pode fazer com que uma mensagem seja considerada como spam:

> A autenticação garante que suas mensagens sejam classificadas corretamente. É provável que os e-mails sem autenticação sejam rejeitados ou colocados na pasta "Spam", devido ao alto risco de serem mensagens falsas usadas em golpes de phishing.

Além disso:

> O domínio remetente deve passar nas verificações SPF ou DKIM. Caso contrário, o e-mail poderá ser marcado como spam.

Seus destinatários precisam ter concordado previamente sobre receber seus emails. Caso contrário, se a Alphabet descobre que você não seguiu essa regra, suas mensagens são spam e pronto. Muitos spammers acabam caindo no filtro do spam por causa justamente dessa regra:

> Cada usuário na sua lista de distribuição deve optar por receber suas mensagens de uma das seguintes formas:
>
> - Por meio de um e-mail solicitando a inscrição na sua lista.
> - Marcando manualmente uma caixa de seleção em um formulário da Web ou em um software.

E ainda:

> Para ajudar a garantir que suas mensagens não sejam marcadas como spam, também recomendamos que você:
>
> - Cancele automaticamente a inscrição de usuários cujos endereços de e-mail rejeitem vários e-mails.
> - Envie periodicamente mensagens de confirmação para os usuários.
> - Inclua cada lista de e-mails em que eles se inscreveram e ofereça a oportunidade de cancelar a inscrição nas listas em que os usuários não estiverem mais interessados.

E finalmente, uma regra que é difícil de contornar:

> Se sua marca ficar associada a spam de marketing de afiliadas, isso poderá afetar os e-mails que você e suas outras afiliadas enviam.

---

Aí você pergunta, por que o seu email enviado via SMTP não deu errado? Se eu tiver que chutar, é porque o processo de envio via SMTP pode ser mais trabalhoso para quem envia, e por isso a IA que verifica os seus emails deve achar que se trata de um teste ou de um email "feito a mão" (ao invés de ser mail em massa/corrente). Por experiência tanto profissional quanto pessoal posso lhe garantir que um sistema que envia muitos emails dessa forma - para qualquer tipo de mensagens, como por exemplo status de um sistema, ou troca de mensagens de SAC - acaba sendo marcado como fonte de spam mais rápido do que você é capaz de dizer "socorro", e reincidência leva a encerramento de conta.

Comment: Renan, entendi, aqui na empresa configuramos tanto SPF quanto DKIM, respeitamos aquele limite do GMAIL API de 32 emails por minuto, e as outras regras do Google(tipo ao pé da letra mesmo)... Conseguimos resolver. Você comentou sobre a autenticação, enviamos um ticket para o Google e pediram para nós autenticarmos o email... não sei se está relacionado ao que você quis dizer... mas resolveu. +1 e vou marcar a resposta ;)

Comment: Renan, agora... me responde uma duvida já que você tem mais experiência aqui. Porque minha pergunta foi tão  negativada? talvez pq achem que eu sou o maluco dos spams?

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti quando o assunto é email marketing, existem somente dois tipos de pessoas: quem acha que é spam e quem envia os emails. É fato que a maioria das empresas que faz isso, inclusive no Brasil, não respeita o opt-out. Principalmente se você não tem conta de email em um provedor de email grande como GMail ou Yahoo! Mail...

Comment: Entendi @Renan ;) obrigado

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti eu tenho meu próprio serviço de email e protejo minha conta com lista branca, ou seja, só recebo mensagens de endereços que eu cadastrei previamente, à mão. Quando eu vejo a lista de rejeição do meu servidor, vejo que recebo aproximadamente 950 emails de "marketing" por dia. Emails que não me interessam. Fiz uma experiência em 2015 e tentei o opt-out dessas listas. Cerca de 3% honraram o opt-out. Quem usa GMail ou outro serviço não vê tantos emails porque esses serviços filtram a maior parte do ruído.

Comment: CA RA CA, não imaginava que era nesse nível !

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti presente de natal atrasado pra você. Leia tudo e se surpreenda: https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-international-email-law-infographic em alguns países você tem um mês para honrar opt-out. Em alguns países você paga mais de dois milhões de reais em multa se deixar de fazer isso. E ainda assim o problema persiste, porque a maior parte do SPAM vem do terceiro mundo (e o Brasil é uma grande parte disso).

Comment: Opa, melhor impossível !, valeu Renan, inclusive me interessei na ideia do próprio serviço de email, vou procurar mais para saber ;)

Answer (score -3):

Encontrei este artigo no stackoverflow.com: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870659/gmail-marking-mails-as-spam-from-my-website

Aparentemente customizar o assunto do e-mail e o conteúdo do e-mail com o nome do destinatário ajuda a escapar desta regra do G-Mail.

Comment: O autor da pergunta comentou na única resposta que essa solução não funciona ;) o filtro anti-spam do GMail envolve aprendizado de máquina sofisticado o suficiente pra não ser enganado por algo tão trivial.